# GraphQL Ruby Subscription Executing Initial Query

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

With [GraphQL Ruby](http://graphql-ruby.org/) it possible to have a GraphQL subscription also return resolves when subscribing? For example:

```
module Types
  class SampleType < GraphQL::Schema::Object
    field :greeting, String, null: false

    def greeting
     'Howdy!'
    end
  end
end

class SampleSchema < GraphQL::Schema
  subscription Types::SampleType
  query Types::SampleType
end

SampleSchema.execute('subscription greeting { greeting }')['data'] # nil - but want the same as query
SampleSchema.execute('query greeting { greeting }')['data'] # { greeting: 'Howdy!' }
```

Note: have found this [Subscription Type](http://graphql-ruby.org/subscriptions/subscription_type.html) documents that specify the return value of the resolver is not used for data (only authorization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of GraphQL-ruby responded to an issue stating:

https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/1910

> No, it's not possible to return something on an initial subscription query. I'm currently working on a new runtime for GraphQL-Ruby and I'll add this issue to my list ([#1884](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/1884)), since many folks have asked for similar improvements to subscriptions.

So not now, maybe later.